# Java problem with parallel 2d arrays and arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to get each row from the jagged array instead of listing each position of the word. The problem is when the user puts in the name of the family, it displays the corresponding list of siblings (parallel arrays, that stores and retrieves the names) afterwards it prompts the user again for the number then it shows the children who are born first, second, etc.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class siblings{
    public static void main (String [] argrs){
        String [] family =  { "Potter", "Weasley", "Grangley", 
                "Dubmbledore", "Black", "Patil", "Creevey"};
        String [] [] siblings = {
                {"harry"},
                {"bill", "charlie", "percry", "fred", "george", "ron", "ginny"},
                {"hermione"},
                {"Ablus","aberforth", "arrianna"},
                {"Sirius", "regulus"},
                {"padma", "pavarti"},
                {"colin", "dennnis"}};


        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a family name: "); 
        String input = kb.next().toLowerCase(); 



        switch (input) {
            case "black" : 
            System.out.println(
                siblings[4][0]+" "+ siblings[4][1]);

            break; 
            case "potter": 
            System.out.println(
                siblings[0][0]); 

            break; 
            case "weasley": 
            System.out.println(
                siblings[1][0]); 

        }




        System.out.println("Enter number between 1-7");
        int input2 = kb.nextInt(); 

        switch (input2) {
            case 1: 
            System.out.println("the names of the 1st born child:");
            System.out.println(
                siblings[0][0]
                +", " 
                +siblings [1][0]
                +", " 
                +siblings [2][0]
                +", " 
                +siblings [3][0]
                +", " 
                +siblings [4][0]
                +", " 
                +siblings [5][0]
                +", " 
                +siblings [6][0]
            );

            break; 
            case 2 : 
            System.out.println("the names of the 2nd born child:");
            System.out.println(
                siblings [1][1]
                +", "  
                +siblings [3][1]
                +", " 
                +siblings [4][1]
                +", " 
                +siblings [5][1]
                +", " 
                +siblings [6][1]
            );

            break; 
            case 3 : 
            System.out.println("the names of the 3nd born child:");
            System.out.println(
                siblings [1][2]
                +", " 
                +siblings [3][2]
            );
            break;

            case 4: 
            System.out.println("the names of the 4th born child:");
            System.out.println(
                siblings [1][3]
            );
            break;

            case 5: 
            System.out.println("the names of the 4th born child:");
            System.out.println(
                siblings [1][4]
            );
            break;

            case 6: 
            System.out.println("the names of the 4th born child:");
            System.out.println(
                siblings [1][5]
            );
            break;

            case 7: 
            System.out.println("the names of the 4th born child:");
            System.out.println(
                siblings [1][6]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you though about using loops and conditions?

Comment: Have you also considered excluding the lesser known Weasley, Percry?  (But in seriousness, the above comment is much better than this.  Additionally, creating an `Object` that represents one such pairing, rather than keeping two arrays in sync is a more object oriented / maintainable / extendable approach.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see my example, start from here and look for generic ways in programming, your approach is too hard-coded, you need to learn loops(while, for), control structures (if, else). Also, see code conventions, you write a bit awkward for java: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/java-naming-conventions/

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//Note, class name must start from capital letter
//See code conventions: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/java-naming-conventions/
public class Siblings {

public static void main (String [] argrs){
    String [] family =  { "Potter", "Weasley", "Grangley", "Dubmbledore", "Black", "Patil", "Creevey"};
    String [] [] siblings = {
            {"harry"},
            {"bill", "charlie", "percry", "fred", "george", "ron", "ginny"},
            {"hermione"},
            {"Ablus","aberforth", "arrianna"},
            {"Sirius", "regulus"},
            {"padma", "pavarti"},
            {"colin", "dennnis"}};


    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a family name selecting one of those: ");
    System.out.println("");
    for(String name: family){
        System.out.print(name);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    String input = kb.next();//note I did not convert to lower case here


    int i = 0;
    String mySiblings[]  = null;
    for(String member: family){
        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(member)){//note how I ignore the case,, when checking
            mySiblings = siblings[i];
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("Siblings of "+input + " are:");

    for(String sibling: mySiblings){
        System.out.print(sibling);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    //Continue your code here

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the help, it looks like i has hard-coding it too hard and completely abandoned the while/for loops to make my life easier.